# What does "**" mean in ANT?

Tags: java, ant

Often in ANT tasks, you will see "**" used similar to below:

```
<copy todir="/something">
  <fileset dir="/source">
    <exclude name="**/*.sql"/>
  </fileset>
</copy>
```

What is the `**` in the name property? I've never seen the style of wildcard. Why is `*.sql` not good enough?

Comment: ** tells it to search through the entire directory tree

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`*.sql` means "in the given directory, all the files that end with .sql"

`**\*.sql` means "in the given directory and inside all of its subdirectories, all the files that end with .sql"

Comment: `**` is documented in the [Patterns section of the ANT manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns).

Comment: Is this just an ANT thing or is this common in general Unix environments as well?

Answer (score 0):

You say *.sql, it only includes sql files but not the sub-directories. If you want to include sql files and also the sql files inside sub-folders, u can use ***/*.sql.